# how to add additional parameters in "profile_center_url" link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a custom profile center link which Salesforce Support already configured. I just want to append additional parameter

`href="%%profile_center_url%%?s=&c=&l=&ee=t&e=%%=SHA256(LOWERCASE(TRIM(emailaddr)))=%%"`

After adding the additional parameter link stops working.

Is there any way to add additional parameters to the profile center url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concat it, like this:

```ampscript
set @profilecenter = 
concat(profile_center_url,'&s=&c=&l=&ee=t&e=',SHA256(LOWERCASE(TRIM(emailaddr))))
```

When using it in the href, remember to use redirectTo:

```ampscript
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@profilecenter)=%%">Your profile</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Lukas, its working...